# Software that shows installed software according to licence of the applications

Tags: apt

I want a software that **shows all installed applications using various sorting options** like date of installation, size of application etc. Most importantly **license** of the application.

I want to ensure that I don't add proprietary software to usb drives and/or cds which would be illegal. I would also like to replace proprietary software with FLOSS software as far as possible. So I need a software that could sort out applications for me.

**EDIT:** USC and Synaptic are both able to show license of software. Also it looks like all proprietary software are included in multiverse repository.

[image]

[image]

So there must be a command to find the license and/or to find which repository a software belongs to.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/334189/get-a-list-of-the-licences-of-all-packages-on-ubuntu-system - there doesn't appear to be an easy answer.